# jsdom can't load local html and javascript

Tags: jsdom

Thanks for any help.

Using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), I'm trying to load a local HTML file, which itself loads a local JS file.

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom-no-contextify'

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require("path");

var html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../src/', 'launcher.html'));

global.document = jsdom.jsdom(html, {
    FetchExternalResources: ['script'],
    ProcessExternalResources: ['script'],
    created: function (error, window) {
        console.log("created: " + error);
    },
    url: "file://mydir/src/js/helloworld.js"
});

global.window = document.parentWindow;

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
});
```

`launcher.html` itself sources `helloworld.js` i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/helloworld.js"></script>
```

However I can't access or read any variables inside `helloworld.js`

Regards, Sam

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the runsScripts and resources properties as below

```
global.document = jsdom.jsdom(html, {
    FetchExternalResources: ['script'],
    ProcessExternalResources: ['script'],
    created: function (error, window) {
        console.log("created: " + error);
    },
    url: "file://mydir/src/js/helloworld.js",
    runScripts: "dangerously",
    resources:'usable'
});
```